# How to ignore/redirect Dataproc System.output calls from java api libraries

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-api-java-client, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using dataproc api library (google-api-services-dataproc) to create clusters and run different hadoop and spark jobs.
The issue I'm having is that the System.out that is happening on the cluster itself is passed to my Java application, which is troublesome as it clutters my logging the main Java app.

`LoggingConfig` property will not help as it only define the logging levels of the logger and I don't want to set a dummy stream (`System.setOut(dummyStream);`) for the output as it will eliminate the output of the jobs in the Dataproc job output in GCP console.

For reference when I was using AWS EMR I was not getting output or loggers back from the EMR cluster that was Initiated in my Java code (`AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.runJobFlow`).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the code you're using? And perhaps the what the output looks like? Job output is streamed to a file in GCS, so unless you're reading it there should be no Job output in your client.

Comment: There is some object preparation before this, but the final call looks like this:
`dataproc.projects().regions().jobs()
        .submit(dataprocClient.getProjectId(), dataprocClient.getRegion(), request).execute()`
when dataproc is  `om.google.api.services.dataproc.Dataproc`.
the output I am getting is the same as I would see in the job output window in GCP.
so lets say I would add `System.out.println("hello 123");` in the Jar I am running on the dataproc machines and I am executing the job using Dataproc api client in my java code, I would see the same print statement in my console.

Comment: @Andreyn you should add this info in your question, not in comments.